# Cannot access worklight server appcenter

Tags: mobile, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Hi i have installed worklight server. By using configuration tool i deployed a war from a dummy project that i created. I also provided all information required without any errors. I created defaultServer (websphere) and i started it (server start command). I can access console: mydomain:9080/mycontextroot/console

but i cant access app center
mydomain:9080/mycontextroot/appcenterconsole or /applicationcenter

the error i get is:

> Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:233'
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /applicationcenter
>   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:233)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>   at [internal classes]
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /applicationcenter
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:496)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:191)
>   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
>   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:195)
>   ... 2 more

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Center is configured separately from deploying a WAR from Studio.  See: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_configuration_of_the_applicati.html

Comment: It says that app center is installed in the initial installation of worklight through the installation manager. But i ve already done that.

Answer (score 1):

If you decided to include the application center as part of the Worklight Server installaltion inside of Installation Manager you may not have the correct context root or you may have not correctly configured it.

In Worklight 6.1 the application center will be installed to a

`http://"server address":"port"/appcenterconsole`

Configuring the Application Center after installation:
https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_configuration_of_the_applicati.html

You can also check your server configuration as well as server file structure to make sure the application center war is included and you have the correct context root. Finally if you do not have the application center installed at all you can install it manually following these instructions:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Fc_installation.html